# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery-1.11.2.min.js

Tags: jquery

http://209.59.138.217/~devsite1/bookdemo/latest/index-sample.html

In Developer Console it returns : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Anybody please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added jQuery twice. One time version 1.8.3 and one time version 1.11.2.
The `jquery.infinitscroll.js` gets loaded in between those 2 versions.

So this means `$.infinitescroll` will be applied inside version 1.8.3. Then it will be overridden by version 1.11.2 which doesn't have this function.

Later down the document you call `$('#content').infinitescroll()` and it will not exist => undefined is not a function.

If you understand this, you'll know what to do.